# Mdx produces repeated values for a measure and across measures

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

The MDX query below is giving me repeated measure values as shown in the result below the query. Sometimes it give me save valuea across different measures.

```
SELECT 
   NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Amount],} ON COLUMNS, 
   NON EMPTY { 
              ( [Date_Time].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * [Date_Time].[Working Day].[Working Day].ALLMEMBERS )
             } 
   DIMENSION PROPERTIES 
   MEMBER_CAPTION, 
   MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME 
   ON ROWS 
FROM [DDS]
where {[Date_Time].[Year].&[2010-01-01T00:00:00] }
```

---

```
Date            working day            Amount
2010-01-01 00:00:00.000      1            19582      
2010-01-02 00:00:00.000      0            19582      
2010-01-03 00:00:00.000      0            19582      
2010-01-04 00:00:00.000      1            19582      
2010-01-05 00:00:00.000      1            19582      
2010-01-06 00:00:00.000      1            19582      
2010-01-07 00:00:00.000      1            19582
```

How can I rectify these issues?

Answer (score 2):

You would get results like this if you have not specified a relationship between the date and the measure group that contains your measure. You would need to go into the dimension usage tab for your cube and fix this.